# numpy array 2d showing in Ellipse Demo

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ellipse

I have an numpy 2d array want to show it inside Ellipse Demo 
the first line is the color and the second is the sum of feeling which is the third line

```
xz = np.array([['E6C637', '1692', 'well'],
       ['7EC31B', '1386', 'free'],
       ['595884', '1032', 'alone'],
       ['40B6B8', '905', 'comfortable'],
       ['99D013', '687', 'fine']])
```

inside this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

NUM = 250

ells = [Ellipse(xy=np.random.rand(2) * 10,
                width=np.random.rand(), height=np.random.rand(),
                angle=np.random.rand() * 360)
        for i in range(NUM)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})
for e in ells:
    ax.add_artist(e)
    e.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
    e.set_alpha(np.random.rand())
    e.set_facecolor(np.random.rand(3))

ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

plt.show()
```

[image: first pic]
[image: second pic]

Comment: The copied code creates 250 random ellipses. How are they related to your data? What do you mean by "sum of filling"? Is this some kind of area? How is the exact size (width, height?) and the location of the ellipses meant to be defined?

Comment: "sum of feeling" sorry for the mistake.

Comment: The height and the width is the size of each plot which is taking the number.
250 random ellipses it is be default I didn't change any thing on this code

Comment: But what is it that you want? 5 ellipses? First ellipse height '1692'? First ellipse width also '1692'? So a circle? At which position?

Comment: please have a look these pictures including more than 1000 elements I don't now what this diagram called

Comment: But what is the relationship between these 1000 elements and your 5 values? The ellipses need at least 4 values for each of them: x, y, width, height. And maybe also rotation angle and arc angle.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows the given data as a [pie chart](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_features.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xz = [['E6C637', '1692', 'well'],
      ['7EC31B', '1386', 'free'],
      ['595884', '1032', 'alone'],
      ['40B6B8', '905', 'comfortable'],
      ['99D013', '687', 'fine']]
labels = [data[2] for data in xz]
sizes = [float(data[1]) for data in xz]
colors = ['#'+data[0] for data in xz]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.
# plt.legend() # show a legend
plt.show()
```

[image: pie chart]